# Изменить тип параметра (string -> string[])

Tags: c#, .net

Есть очень много кода где вызывается метод с подобной сигнатурой:
    `SomeMethod(string str);`

И с течением времени для нового функционала нужно передать массив строк:

`SomeMethod(string[] strs);`

Вопрос: как можно "безболезненно" изменить параметр с `string` на `string[]`, кроме как передачи параметра как `object` или перегрузки метода(перегрузка приводит к сильному разрастанию кода, так как вызвать один метод внутри второго не получится)?

Comment: Почему вы считаете, что вызвать один метод внутри другого не получится?

Comment: Потому что этот метод ~500 строк и взаимодействует с COM. И если вызывать один внутри второго то будет происходить "перезапись нужных данных, а не установка всех нужных компонентов"..

Comment: Вы почему-то исходите из того, что у вас внутри 500 строк один метод вызывает другой. Но так делать и не следует! Должен быть один "эталонный" метод, принимающий все необходимые параметры, состоящий из тех самых 500 строк - и несколько "сокращений", принимающих другие параметры и не делающие абсолютно ничего, кроме вызова эталонного (по 1 строке на каждый метод).

Comment: @PavelMayorov, думаю это очевидно.. Если бы я этот код писал с нуля, а не поддерживал код n-годичной давности, я бы так и сделал..

Comment: Нет никакой разницы. Если уж вы собрались менять тип одного из параметров - то написать перегрузку-обертку - это меньшая из проблем.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Поменяйте параметр на

```
SomeMethod(params string[] strs);
```

Можно будет вызывать и с передачей одного string, и с передачей массива. И заодно с передачей нескольких строк через запятую:

```
SomeMethod("a", "b", "c");
```

Comment: Спасибо. Вы полностью ответили на мой вопрос. А как быть например если несколько параметров, и этот параметр в начале?

Comment: Тогда - только перегрузка.